# Why does a Missing Partial error occur occasionally when the file exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While running Cucumber tests, from time to time it will fail intermittently. The error is:

```
*** ActionView::Template::Error Exception: Missing partial items/_fields with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "/my/path/to/application/app/views"
  * "/my/path/to/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views"
  * "/my/path/to/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/devise-3.5.4/app/views"
```

Yes, the partial file does exist in `/my/path/to/application/app/views/items/_fields.html.haml`

The kicker is that sometimes the test will pass, other times it will fail. I am running on a Red Hat 5 machine.

So to debug this, I decided to throw in a `begin/rescue`.

```
.fields
  - begin
    = render partial: 'items/fields', locals: {f: f}
  - rescue Exception => e
    = byebug

  - if f.can_modify?(:object_a)
    = render partial: 'layouts/object_a_field', locals: {f: f, field: :object_a}
   - else
    .field#object_a
      = render partial: 'layouts/attribute', locals: {label: 'Object A', value: f.object.object_a_id ? f.object.object_a_number : 'Not Assigned'}

    .field#name
    - if f.can_modify?(:name)
      = f.label :name
      = f.text_field :name, {class: 'inputbox large_field', readonly: f.cannot_modify?(:name)}
      .smltxt (short description of the item)
    - else
      = render partial: 'layouts/attribute', object: f.object, locals: {field: :name}
```

For those curious what's in the partial `items/fields`:

```
.field
  - if f.can_modify?(:name)
    = f.label :name, 'Item'
    = f.text_field :name, {class: 'inputbox uppercase', maxlength: 16, readonly: !f.object.identifier.new_record?}
    .smltxt (character identifier)
  - else
    = render partial: 'layouts/attribute', object: f.object, locals: {field: :name, label: 'Item'}
```

When it passes, I obviously don't hit the byebug, but when it fails, I do! Which allows me to play with it in a Rails Console type environment.

So I decided to run that specific command:

```
(byebug) render partial: 'items/fields', locals: {f: f}
```

And I get:

```
*** ActionView::Template::Error Exception: Missing partial items/_fields with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "/my/path/to/application/app/views"
  * "/my/path/to/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views"
  * "/my/path/to/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/devise-3.5.4/app/views"
```

So I thought I'd remove the locals to see if anything changed:

```
(byebug) render partial: 'items/fields'
```

And I get:

```
*** ActionView::Template::Error Exception: undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x0000002a907610>:0x00000027beae48>
```

So obviously it's now magically finding the partial, and it knows that it is missing a local variable `f`.

**Update 1**

I added the rest of the view that is calling the partial above for clarity.

In an attempt to troubleshoot, I also took the contents of `items/_fields.html.haml` and placed it where I had the `render partial: 'items/fields', locals: {f: f}`... then the test passed, which means that the other partials in the file didn't have an issue either. So it doesn't seem like it could be related to the content of the file.

**Update 2**

It seems by adding the @javascript tag to our very first Cucumber feature often fixes this issue. Somehow having the browser loaded before the other tests, improves the chances of it passing. Makes no sense to me, maybe someone else has an idea about this?

**Update 3**

It has been discovered today that the error is not related to Cucumber at all. The same error was found in production. The web interface showed a Missing Partial error, but for a file that did indeed exist. After restarting the Passenger server with `touch tmp/restart.txt` and then the error went away. So it's still very intermittent.

**Update 4**

I added the content of the partial that seems to be missing randomly.

**How would I go about discovering why Rails cannot find a partial that is actually there?**

Comment: I actually had similar issue with existing partials few days ago in development. Trying to remember what I did, but can't. Indeed the partial was there, and it interchangeably worked/not worked..

Comment: Can you show `Gemfile.lock` ?  
the reason maybe in gems

Comment: Can you show params hash from production? Maybe format is not html in some cases

Comment: Marat, due to sensitive information, I cannot include the Gemfile.lock at this time.

bbozo, that's an interesting thought. I'll look into that.

Tilo, I don't understand how that would matter. This is on my development machine, running Cucumber tests.

Comment: It would be great if you would strip the app down to a minimal app (single controller, single action, only the necessary gems) where the error occurs and publish it e.g. as a github repo for experimenting.

Comment: Case sensitive filesystem? Next time you hit the `byebug` do `File.exists?('/my/path/to/application/app/views/items/_fields.html.haml')`. If the file does not exist, try `Dir.glob('/my/path/to/application/app/views/items/*`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly believe upgrading to Ruby 2.3.1 solved this for us. I am not certain what may have changed. When we were investigating this, my colleague and I thought we found a line in the Rails source code that was rendering partials differently based on the Ruby version.

I'm having trouble finding that now, but I still wanted to post that the problems seems to have vanished ever since we upgraded to a newer Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

This error usually happens when the format of the request is different and there is no template that can respond to it example `format.js`, `format.html` etc. The request will only work if the template `items/_fields.html.haml` is a it will only be correct if the request format is html

I think you can rename your file to `items/_fields.haml` if you want to use to respond it any request format.

Comment: Probably, sometimes the format of the request is ajax-based `format.js` and sometimes its directly `format.html` ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but with another gem for handlebars. It is usually because of caching.

Try in your cucumber setup setting

```
ActionView::Base.cache_template_loading = false
```

If the above works you **DO** have a caching issue that will occur on production.

There is an open issue for caching not being enabled in dev mode here: https://github.com/indirect/haml-rails/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cache_template_loading

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try specifying the format and handler of the partial you're rendering:

```
= render(
  partial: 'items/fields',
  formats:  [:html],
  handlers: [:haml],
  locals: {f: f}
)
```

Comment: I can give that a shot, but it doesn't really make sense why I would need to specify that the format is html or that the handler is haml. The error mentions that both of there were included in the search.

Comment: @ardavis so you say that specifying `formats` and `handlers` adds no value, right?

Comment: I haven't been able to check if adding the `formats` and `handlers` would add value. Even if that did work, it would just be a band-aid. It doesn't explain why the other partials work.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the file from your terminal to see whether it's available or not.
If you can't find it from the terminal, go to your app folder in your text editor and delete it manually.

After that, use the terminal to create it again.

It appears the file is not readable even though it is visible in your text editor, but not visible when accessing it from the terminal.

For some weird reason, this works.

**Note:** Same applies to folders